# How to make global variable in Lumen PHP framework

Tags: laravel, lumen

I am pretty new in Lumen.

Cause Lumen don't have config folder, how to make global variable that I will use in all controllers.

Comment: Save the variable the session

Comment: According to the documentation, Lumen does have config files.

Answer (score 3):

You can use Dotenv.

To do so, uncomment `Dotenv::load(__DIR__.'/../');` in `bootstrap/app.php` and place your global variable in the `.env` at the root of your lumen project.
For example, I add :

```
FRONT_PATH = http://localhost/account
```

Then, you can call the `env()` function with the name of your global variable

```
env("FRONT_PATH")
```

It returns your variable or `null` if it doesn't exist.

you can also specify a custom default value :

```
env("FRONT_PATH", false)
```

Answer (score -3):

Laravel : save variable in session

```
Session::put('name','John Doe');
```

The variable name will persist in the session till it is flushed out. To access variable

```
Session::get('name') or in Laravel 5.x session('name') .
```

Check the documentation for more info.

Comment: The topic is about Lumen, which doesn't use sessions.